# Add layout in <include /> programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, include

I have the following xml:

fragment1.xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/customized_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 />
..
/>
```

In this Fragment how can I add programmatically the layout I want to include in the `customized_layout`?

I have the following:

```
@InjectView (R.id. customized_layout) RelativeLayout customLayout;
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

      //customLayou.addLayout(...) ??
    }
```

Comment: why there is a -1 vote? I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate `xml`. And add `view` to a container.

```
LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,null);
container.addView(view);
```

Comment: I get the error message: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />

Comment: You do not have to use include tag when inflating dynamically just use a LinearLayout and it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dynamic layout is :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     .........
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity:

```
LinearLayout dynamicLayout = findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout)
customLayout.addView(dynamicLayout)
```